# Is there a way to have groupings of bars in a bar chart in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, charts, libreoffice-calc

I know this may be bad style, but I want a bar chart that groups certain bars together. For example if I was comparing the speed of two models of cars, and considering the speed under wet and dry conditions how would I show it all in one chart?

I want something that looks like this

[image: Example of what I'm trying to do]

I'm using OpenOffice 4 but am willing to use a different program, such as Microsoft Excel 2010 or google docs.

Comment: That is how the graph would look if you had two series in it. Data in two columns with 2 rows of data in each column.  In excel at least and I'm pretty sure open office as well

Comment: @gtwebb could you please explain more as what you mean, for example give an example. What is a "series"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having grouped columns is the normal way excel displays bar charts with multiple series.  The following has 2 series.  Series dry has a series name selected as B1 and data as B2:B3.  Series green has name=C1 and data C2:C3.

The horizontal axis label is equal to A2:A3 which gives the model 1 and 2 labels.

[image]